# SELECT if any row within ID contains specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DB with IDs and their classification (and much more columns that are useless for now),
Due to differences in unused columns, one ID may have different classifications like:

```
ID        Classification

1001      A
1001      A

1002      A
1002      A
1002      B
```

What I need is to group IDs and put classification by the rule "If any of the lines within this ID is 'B'-classified, then the group (single row with this ID) is 'B'-classified, else - 'A'-classified.

So that ID `1001 = A`, but ID `1002 = B`.

I am aware of `WHERE tab.field = ANY()` function, but I have reciprocal situation - left part of comparison should be ANY, while right part should be hardcoded. I kind of assume, that as comparison result is boolean, than place of left\right parts is irrelevant, but I cannot figure out query-subquery relations.

Please help

Comment: could you do a `GROUP BY ID` in combination with a `MAX(Classification)`, relying on the fact that 'B' > 'A'?

Comment: Can the value in classification be only A or B?

Comment: Currently there are only 2 classification cases\values (they are not 'A' and 'B', but also strings, so can be compared). I just wanted to make universal solution for possible future changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` window function to do this.

```
select distinct id
,case when count(case when classification='B' then 1 end) over(partition by id) >=1 then 'B' else 'A' end as classified
from t
```

Comment: works like a charm! used it as universal solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the special case where the classification of interest is also the letter with the last alphabetical position, you can simply do:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  MAX(Classification)
FROM tab
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find max of classification for each id:

```
select id,
    max(classification)
from your_table
group by id;
```